# How to sort the data from CSV file by comparing data from text file using awk output it as a TXT file?

Tags: shell-script, awk, csv

There are two files I am going to extract the data:

file1.txt:

```
Type Serial ID Element Hit_Possibility
Yasuo 19-2 19623 Hasaki
```

file2.csv:

```
Date,Name,Order,Hit Possibility
12-Aug,Ken,1,256
12-Aug,Tom,19,498
12-Aug,Ray,36,753
```

How can I combine two files into a text file with the following results:

```
Type Serial ID Element Hit_Possibility
Yasuo 19-2 19623 Hasaki 498
```

Here is what I have tried before:

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" 'NR==1{print $0;next} NR==FNR{Arr[$2]=$NF;next}{split($2,b,"-");if(b[1] in Arr){print $0,Arr[b[1]]}}' file2.csv file1.txt
```

I think I cannot get the results because of the NR==FNR part. How can I get the  result file I want?

Comment: What is the key to combine data from these two files?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this awk:

```
awk -F, '
   (NR==FNR)&&(NR>1){a[$3]=$4;next}  # Get keys of file2 into array a
   ($2 in a){$0=$0 a[$2]}            # If key in file1 is part of the array a, append value
   NR!=1                             # Print all lines of file1 and file2 except the header
' file2 FS='[ -]' file1
```

Comment: clever change of FS between file !! I dunno you can do that !

Answer (score 0):

You could simplfy oliv's answer a bit:

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR     {a[$3] = $4
             next}
            {print $0, a[$2]
            }
' file2 FS='[ -]' file1
Type Serial ID Element Hit_Possibility 
Yasuo 19-2 19623 Hasaki  498
```